# While resampling, my original data has no null values but then when I resample for mean values, it generates a bunch of nulls?

Tags: python-3.x

I cant figure this one out. While resampling, my original data has no null values but then when I resample for mean values, it generates a bunch of nulls?

It is not the whole of df that turns into NaN's

```
len(df) 
Out[425]: 8624066

df[['Bid','Ask','spread','mid']].isnull().sum()
Out[421]: 
Bid       0
Ask       0
spread    0
mid       0
dtype: int64

df[['Bid','Ask','spread','mid']].resample('min').mean().isnull().sum()
Out[422]: 
Bid       170459
Ask       170459
spread    170459
mid       170459
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Sorry for the poorly formatted Question. Hopefully it is still legible.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Is this using Pandas? Better include that in the question, or better yet, tag the question with [pandas] so people can find it.

Comment: You might also find it helpful to split your problem into a small enough size so that you can see individual rows of input data and output data. It's much easier (for you and for us) to understand what's happening when there are 8 rows instead of 8000000.

Comment: You did not provide any sample data so it is hardly possible to say anything specific about the problem. You have 2 layers of processing - (1) resampling with `minute` rule and (2) computing mean. Follow @RJHunter's advice - process small piece of data in step by step fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice. It was annoying to dig into, but it turns out that the original data does have a few periods (longer than a minute) where no trades were registered. So the re-sample method obviously couldn't aggregate for those minutes. It also explains why there were no NaN values in the original data but there was after the re-sampling.